# I need to remove specific elements in an ArrayList which may appear more than once

Tags: java

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError and other ArrayList errors when trying to remove specific elements from an ArrayList which may contain that element more than once.

I have tried doing a manual linear search by removing the index(s) which contain the specified element, but also could not get it to work, as int i in the loop would not equal 0 after the first loop (I set up an if statement which would assign i to 0 at the very beginning of the loop if satisfied).

```
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String> (); /* List which will have some of its elements removed */
        ArrayList<String> rem = new ArrayList<String> (); /* List containing the elements which will be removed */
        ArrayList<Boolean> bool = new ArrayList<Boolean> (); /* List which will indicate if the removal of an element taken place in the previous loop */
        /**/
        s.add("hello");
        s.add("hello");
        s.add("your");
        s.add("hi");
        s.add("there");
        s.add("hello");
                /**/
        rem.add("hello");
        rem.add("hi");
        /**/
        int len=s.size();
        /*loop for bool*/
        for (int j=0; j<len; ++j) {
            /* loop for rem */
            for (int i=0; i<rem.size(); ++i) {
                if (j>=1) {
                    if (bool.get(j-1)==true) i=0; /* If an element (from rem) had been removed from s in the previous loop, then it will continue looking for looking for that same element (from rem) until it has removed all instances of it. Then it moves to the next element in rem and removes those elements from s and so on. **/
                }
                if (s.contains(rem.get(i))) {
                    s.remove(rem.get(i));
                    bool.add(true); 
                }
                else bool.add(false); 
            }
        }
        /* prints ArrayList<String> s after it has been through the removal process */
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println(s.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: You could use `Set`, to remove the elements occurring more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing so:

1. You can perform reverse iteration:

```java
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add("hello");
// add more Strings...

ArrayList<String> rem = new ArrayList<>();
rem.add("hello");
// add more Strings to remove...

for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    if (rem.contains(s.get(i)) {
        s.remove(i);
    }
}
```

2. Using [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```java
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add("hello");
// add more Strings...

ArrayList<String> rem = new ArrayList<>();
rem.add("hello");
// add more Strings to remove...

s.removeAll(rem);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will get into a `dead` circle because of `"if (bool.get(j-1)==true) i=0"`, because it always make `i=0`.

Comment: For that reason, I made an outer loop specifically for bool. The idea was that it would make a tracker for bool for each loop. Would the reason for why this wouldn't work be because that loop (with j) is outside of the inner loop (with i) and it would never passed through until the inner loop has completed?

Answer (score 2):

Better option would be to use `Set`

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String> ();
 s.add("hello");
 s.add("hello");
 s.add("your");
 s.add("hi");
 s.add("there");
 s.add("hello");

 Set<String> set=new HashSet<>(s);

 System.out.println(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting out of memory, when adding a new element to `bool` it is because of this line:

`i = 0; /* If an element (from rem) had been removed from s in the previous loop, then it will continue looking for looking for that same element (from rem) until it has removed all instances of it. Then it moves to the next element in rem and removes those elements from s and so on. **/`

You are setting to 0 the value of your iteration variable.
As a consequence this line: `else bool.add(false)` is being hit far too many times. Until when I stopped trying it was hit (and therefore had this amount of elements): 88 times.

This is obviously wrong.